# MySQL LEFT JOIN only on some rows?

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table:

[image]

On this table, I want to LEFT JOIN another table, but only to rows with **`action == 2`** or **`action == 3`**. Is this possible with one SELECT by somehow specifying the  LEFT JOIN part, or do I need to do more SELECTs and a UNISON?

EDIT: Rows with action = 1 can simply contain NULL values from the LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM sometable
LEFT JOIN jointable ON (sometable.field = jointable.field AND (action IN (2,3)))
```

you can have arbitrary logic in the JOIN conditions. All it has to do in the end is boil down to a true/false value. If the result is true, the join is successful and the joined fields are included. if the result is false, then the join does not occur for that particular row combination.

Comment: Amazing solution and explanation! This should be what I'm looking for. I'm going to try this out right now.

Comment: @ziul: I always explicitly parenthesize. That way I don't have to try to remember the precedence rules for whatever language I'm working in - the brackets enforce **MY** precedence.

Comment: Show me a SQL based language with diferent boolean rules and i'll upvote you.

Comment: @ziul: consider that there's more than just sql in the world. I work with about 8 different languages on a daily basis, including ones where you're doing multi-language embedding (e.g. php -> html -> js, php -> sql). I'd rather just hit `(` and `)` a few extra times v.s. yanking my train of thought onto different tracks each time.

Comment: So do i, i was just curios if you could find an answer to my question =D, none of the language you mentioned is.

Comment: I did. explicit bracket means I don't have to "Oh, I'm doing sql. I can do X" v.s. "and now it's LIMS-basic, gotta do Y". I just ignore the language itself and bracket the logic the way I want. doesn't matter if sql is the same everywhere, I just remove the fact that's it sql from the equation completely.

Comment: Maybe as a beginner example, but for maintanable code i dont think is a good practice... and boolean rules are a pretty broad standard, so the parentheses are pretty pointless. Anyway, this is turning into a discussion in the comments, so it ends here.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t LEFT JOIN another_table AS at ON t.id = at.id WHERE t.action = 2 OR t.action = 3
```

Doesn't this give you the result you are looking for?